# Call a Form and correct way to release? memory usage

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using Delphi 7.

I have two units containing `Form1` and `Form2`. The secondary form will be called many times during some process, and I am very worried about memory usage.

When I start the program, memory usage is around 2.1 MB. When `Form2` is called, memory grows to 2.9 MB.  After this process, I close `Form2` and call it again to simulate regular usage, and memory grows to 3.1 MB, call again and memory grows to 3.4 MB, 3.6 MB, 3.8 MB, etc.

Memory usage is the main issue.

`Form1` is calling `Form2` like this:

```
uses
  Unit2;

...

private
  { Private declarations }
  FChild : TForm2;
...      

FChild := TForm2.Create(nil);
try
  FChild.ShowModal;
finally
  FChild.Free;
end;
```

Inside `Unit2`:

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better solution?

Please, this not a simple question, because this program will be running 24 hours, and the second form will be called many times.  This means that sometimes this program will freeze the computer.

I included FASTMM4 inside project:

```
program Project1;

uses
  FastMM4,
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  FullDebugModeScanMemoryPoolBeforeEveryOperation := True;
  SuppressMessageBoxes:=False;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

This program is reading a fingerprint.

Unit1:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnForm2: TButton;
    btnReselease: TButton;
    procedure btnForm2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnReseleaseClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FChild : TForm2;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnForm2Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
  FChild := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    FChild.ShowModal;
  finally
    FChild.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnReseleaseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FChild <> nil then
  begin
    FreeAndNil(FChild);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Unit2:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons, pngimage, ExtCtrls, Grids,  XMLIntf, XMLDoc,
  ComCtrls, CPort;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    btnSyncFP: TBitBtn;
    btnExitFP: TBitBtn;
    btnDeleteFP: TBitBtn;
    btnCaptureFP: TBitBtn;
    ComImage: TImage;
    FPGrid: TStringGrid;
    prgBar: TProgressBar;
    lblbar: TLabel;
    ComPortA: TComPort;
    ComDataPacket1: TComDataPacket;
    procedure LoadUsers2;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComPortAAfterOpen(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComPortAAfterClose(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnExitFPClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
//  Form2: TForm2;
  L1, L2: TStringList;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.LoadUsers2;
var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  CurNode, CNode : IXMLNODE;
  i : Integer;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.LoadFromFile('usuario.xml');
  XML.Active := True;
  CurNode := XML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0]; // users
  FPGrid.RowCount := CurNode.ChildNodes.Count+1;
  prgBar.Min := 0;
  prgBar.Max := CurNode.ChildNodes.Count-1;
  lblBar.Caption := 'Carregando usuários...';
  for i := 0 to CurNode.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
  begin
    CNode := CurNode.ChildNodes[i]; // groups
    with CNode do
    begin
      FPGrid.Cells[2,i+1] := Attributes['group'];
      FPGrid.Cells[1,i+1] := Attributes['id'];
      FPGrid.Cells[0,i+1] := Attributes['name'];
      FPGrid.Cells[3,i+1] := Attributes['fingerID'];
      FPGrid.Cells[4,i+1] := Attributes['level'];
      FPGrid.Cells[5,i+1] := Attributes['status'];
    end;
    if FPGrid.Cells[3,i+1]<>'' then L1.Add(FPGrid.Cells[3,i+1]);
    prgBar.Position := i;
  end;
  XML := nil;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadUsers2;
  with FPGrid do
  begin
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Font.Size := 12;
    ColCount := 4;
    Cells[0,0] := 'Name';  Cells[1,0] := 'ID';
    Cells[2,0] := 'Group'; Cells[3,0] := 'Read ID';
    Cells[4,0] := 'Level'; Cells[5,0] := 'Status';
    ScrollBars := ssVertical;
    Options := Options + [goRowSelect];
  end;
  ComPortA.Open;
end;

procedure TForm2.ComPortAAfterOpen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('conn_on.png');
end;

procedure TForm2.ComPortAAfterClose(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('conn_off.png');
end;

procedure TForm2.btnExitFPClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComPortA.Close;
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

I know that Task Manager is the best to verify leak memory, but after few hours, the program is growing faster and not realeasing memory.

I let the program running all night and memory is backing, but there is a long time not enough as user usage.

Comment: Tested with a brand new D7 project; cannot duplicate. Private working set stable around 1MB according to taskmgr.

Comment: And 24/7 guy sitting by the computer seeing (and filling) your forms opened at any time is fine? Well, except that, you're not doing anything wrong in my my point of view. Memory manager does then. The code seems to be fine (so long you allocate and release resources properly).

Comment: ... you don't need "caFree" of course, you are freeing the form yourself. That's not related with any leaks though...

Comment: Sigh, please provide [mcve]

Comment: David...I added the complete code.

Comment: btnReseleaseClick looks like a double free. You seem be trying to free the same thing over and over again.

Comment: A dirty trick to release memory is using the SetProcessWorkingSetSize API. But if you really have a memory leak somewhere it wont help you.

Comment: @GuidoG It's almost always a bad idea carried out by people who don't understand virtual memory.

Comment: Global variables, ***ALARM BELLS!!!*** You have code that could add to a global `TStringList` every time you create the form: `if FPGrid.Cells[3,i+1]<>'' then L1.Add(FPGrid.Cells[3,i+1]);`. Nothing you've presented counteracts that, and it's a strong candidate for your memory leak. Of course you haven't shown a ***complete*** [mcve]. So there may be something else at play. All the more reason you should put the effort in to create an **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, apart from a potential error where the form may be "Freed" twice, you appear to be doing everything correctly, assuming that your **Form2** implementation does not itself introduce memory leaks.

I am assuming that you are monitoring "memory use" by using *Task Manager*.  If so, this is highly misleading.

Your application is managing its memory using the Delphi heap manager.  This heap manager will allocate memory (requesting it from the OS) as required but when it is freed it is not immediately returned to the system (OS), but simply marked as no longer in use.  Then, when memory is required by the application in the future, the heap manager can "recycle" this unused memory instead of having to go back to the OS to ask for more memory (which is a relatively "expensive" operation).

However, the way that the heap manager determines whether unused memory can be recycled to satisfy a new request can mean that memory that could potentially be recycled may not be, for example as the result of fragmentation.

Imagine your application allocated 500 bytes of memory then a further 100 bytes and then another 500 bytes:

```
[1] [used] 500 bytes
[2] [used] 100 bytes
[3] [used] 500 bytes
```

Imagine then that the two 500 bytes blocks are freed, making them available for re-use.

```
[1] [free] 500 bytes
[2] [used] 100 bytes
[3] [free] 500 bytes
```

You might think that a request for 1000 bytes (or even 600, 700, 800 bytes etc) would be able to use this "recyclable" memory.

But that request for 1000 bytes requires a single, contiguous block, and with that 100 byte block still in use, those two 500 byte blocks can only be used for requests for (a maximum of) 500 bytes each.  So, a request for 1000 bytes has to be satisfied by allocating a *new* 1000 byte block:

```
[1] [free] 500 bytes
[2] [used] 100 bytes
[3] [free] 500 bytes
[4] [used] 1000 bytes
```

Your application is still only "using" 1100 bytes, but to do so, 2100 bytes have been allocated from the OS.

The net result of all this is that memory "use" can appear to grow in Task Manager when in fact what is really happening is that your application is simply "holding on" to allocated memory it is no longer actually using, just in case it might need it in the future.

If the OS reached a point where it needed memory back, then all processes would be asked to relinquish such memory, and your application would be no different.

You can simulate this by minimising and restoring your application.  Unless your application is genuinely using all of the memory currently allocated, you should see a drop in memory use.  This drop might be slight or it could be significant, depending on the memory usage profile of your application.

When a (Delphi) application is minimized it will return some/as much memory to the system, on the basis that if the user has minimized it then it is now a "backgrond" process which is not likely to need to have any demands for memoy in the near future.

You can trigger this behaviour with some code in your application **OnIdle** event, but doing so is mostly pointless.  It may give the *impression* of reduced memory use in *Task Manager*, but will potentially reduce performance of your application and doesn't actually reduce your memory usage.

### What Can I Do About It ?

The Delphi runtime has always supported the ability to replace the application heap manager with alternative implementations.

A popular one (which has been adopted as the new standard since Delphi 2006) is [FastMM](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4).  This implements strategies that avoid or reduce memory fragmentation and provides other performance and debugging improvements (it can be configured to report memory leaks and incorrectly used references to destroyed objects, for example).

FastMM  is open source and can be used even in a Delphi 7 application.  All you need to do is download the source and add **FastMM** as the first unit used in your project **dpr** file.

Comment: A double free is not possible. The queue is not pumped after CM_RELEASE is posted and before the form's window is destroyed, hence the posted message will never reach its destined window.

Comment: Yes, hence the "potential" qualification on the "error".  :)   Currently the two directives to Free the form do not actually result in the form being Freed twice, but two separate freeing mechanisms are implemented in the code.  So whether as a result of future refactoring or a change in runtime, this *could* lead to a double free error arising, if those two mechanisms are not resolved into one.  In any event, this is not related to the perceived "problem" in this case.

Comment: Thank you, for your excellent information. I don't if a misunderstood, but I tried to minimize the program and restore, but there is no change of memory usage. I include FASTMM4 and enable report (put complete source code including DPR) and there are no problems, but the memory is not releasing.

Comment: The minimize/maximize "trick" isn't *guaranteed* to release any memory, only to trigger the application to release what memory it can, and that might be none.  This doesn't necessarily indicate any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Action := caFree` and `Free()` together on the same object.  Use one or the other, not both.  The call to `Free()` will actually cancel out the `Action:=caFree`, making it redundant.

But that is not the cause of your problem.

The code you have shown is fine in general, `Form2` gets freed from memory correctly. What you are not taking into account is that Delphi's Memory Manager simply does not release freed memory back to the OS, it holds on to it and reuses it for future allocations.  If you are using Task Manager to track memory usage, that is not a good tool for diagnosing memory leaks, since it has no concept of how Delphi caches freed memory over time.

However, that being said, the growth you describe sounds more like memory fragmentation rather than a memory leak.   But it is hard to say for sure since you did not show what all is actually on Form2, or provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue.

In any case, Delphi 7's default memory manager wasn't very efficient in general.  That is why Borland eventually switched to [FastMM](https://fastmm.sourceforge.net) in Delphi 2006.  You could try replacing the default memory manager with a newer one and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use FastMM. See [article](https://wiert.me/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/) and add FastMM.

If you can, create separated build configuration with fully enabled FastMM diagnostics and run it i. e. before merging to master git branch. I use this strategy and greatly increase quality of my code, without any drawbacks (FastMM diagnostics are kinda heavy  for compiler, but I run them not often, so it's ok).